# Internet Explorer 7 + alert() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

Can some of you please tell me why a simple `alert()` isn't working using jQuery 1.4 in Internet Explorer 7, when it's working in all other browsers? It's been driving me crazy now for the last half an hour..!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("wtf?");
})
```

This simple example doesn't show an alert in IE7.  See for yourself at http://jsfiddle.net/8HQdp/.

Comment: `alert()` is a JS function which has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: @Lekensteyn You mean it has nothing to do with JQuery..

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Without intending to be pedantic, `alert()` is not a JS function, it is a DOM function.

Comment: @Don Pedro: Do you look at it in native IE7 or IE8 in IE7 mode?

Comment: I'm using a "package" which had both IE6, IE7 and IE8 in it (just for browser optimizing).. I'll see if I can try to find a link for you

Comment: http://utilu.com/IECollection <-- this one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Ensure your console doesn't show any errors and correct them if there are any.
2. Be sure you didn't disable browser prompts on IE
3. Try using `window.alert()` - it's possible (though improbable) that another `alert()` is conflicting with `window`'s.
4. If you have console support, try `console.log(alert);` and see what it says. It should be something like:

   ```
   function alert() {
       [native code]
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using IE8 but with IE7 mode, the alert on http://jsfiddle.net/8HQdp/ still triggers.
Try changing $ to jQuery and host your own jquery.js.

And also try console.log('wtf') before alert so u know whether it's alert or document.ready is broken.

Comment: The console.log will break IE for sure, since it doesn't know a window.console property... Better do something obvious, like `$('body').hide()`. +1 for testing to see, what's broken.

Comment: Tried with Boldewyn's suggestion, and it hides the body.. So it's 100% that document.ready is working just fine.. http://jsfiddle.net/8HQdp/3/

Answer (score 0):

It works in IE 7 mode in IE 8 form me. Takes a while but it does trigger.

I noticed that there is a semi colon missing from the ready function. should be...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

}); //missing semicolon here
```

Also, try using the shortcut for the DOM ready function...

```
$(function(){
   // code here
});
```

Comment: Ah, ye - my bad.. I was too fast with the example :) But it's still not working in IE7 unfortunately, neither with the shortcut :/ http://jsfiddle.net/8HQdp/4/

Comment: I did notice that there is an object error occurring when in IE 7 that has nothing to do with your code, I think its a bug with jsfiddle itself. Have you tried it in firefox or some other browser that works?

Answer (score -1):

Try using `window` not `document`.

Comment: The `window` will always be kind of "ready". It's `document`, that's no error: http://api.jquery.com/ready/ Hence -1.